# Extension of Kollár's Vanishing Theorem to non-projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Kollár's Vanishing Theorem claims the following:

> **Theorem:** Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a surjective morphism of connected smooth projective varieties over a field $k$ of char. $0$. Then the complex  $\mathbf{R}f_*\Omega^{\dim X}_X$ is concentrated in degrees $[0, \dim X - \dim Y]$.

It seems that the projectivity assumption is really used in the proof, I wonder if this is an artifact of the proof.

Question $1$: Is the same result known for a morphism of smooth and proper varieties over a field of char. $0$?

Question $2$: Is the same result known for a proper morphism of smooth varieties over a field of char. $0$?

Question $3$: Is the same result known for a proper morphism of smooth *complex-analytic spaces*?

Remark $4$: In the case of a birational morphism $f$, it seems that the result holds for any proper morphism between smooth varieties. One uses the Factorization Theorem to reduce to the case of a blow-up with a smooth center. Then one uses Grothendieck duality to reduce the question to show that $\mathbf{R}f_*\mathcal O_X=\mathcal O_Y$ that can be computed explicitly.

Comment: Yes for Q1 and Q2. Yes for Q3, if $X$ Kähler (but I don't expect it in general). For Q1 use the fact that the statement is local on $Y$. For Q2 use the "Lefschetz principle"  or more precisely, that cohomology commutes extension of the ground field. For Q3, look at my old paper "A note on Kollár's theorem" for example. By the way, your statement is a lot weaker than Kollár vanishing.

Comment: @DonuArapura Great, thanks! I am a bit confused by your hint to Q2, though I think one can firstly prove the result for a projective morphism of smooth varieties by reducing to the theorem of Kollár, and then use Chow's Lemma (and resolution of singularities) to give the proof in the proper case.

Comment: @DonuArapura Thanks for pointing out your paper. But it seems that you still need to assume that $Y$ is projective. Do you expect the result to be true without algebraic assumptions on Y? Or under some weaker assumption, e.g. $Y$ is Kähler or the Hodge-to-de Rham spectral sequence degenerates for $Y$.

Comment: True, I assumed algebraicity of the base. A better reference, assuming only Kählerness of $X$, is Takegoshi "Higher direct images...", Math. Ann. (1995).